# jQuery leaks solved, but why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am working on a large enterprise application with a LOT of JavaScript. Enough that I can't possibly go through and fix all the small circular references that have been created over its past 5 years of development. While researching solutions I came across this small jQuery hack/patch:

http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/07/ie-memory-leak-jquery-garbage-collector/

and decided to try it. Amazingly, it works! sIEVE shows no leaks in the places I had previously identified them and the iexplore task is maintaining a more manageable memory footprint.

My question is, why does this work? jQuery.remove calls .removeChild, which should get rid of the element, but apparently does not. The patch instead appends the target element onto a new garbage collector div, which it then clears. Why does the patch method of removal completely free up the memory but jQuery's remove function does not? I'm hoping to understand why this works in order to possibly improve the solution before I check it in to the larger application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the `.remove` method in the current jQuery release (1.6.2). Notice that it calls `.cleanData`:

```
// keepData is for internal use only--do not document
    remove: function( selector, keepData ) {
        for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
            if ( !selector || jQuery.filter( selector, [ elem ] ).length ) {
                if ( !keepData && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                    jQuery.cleanData( elem.getElementsByTagName("*") );
                    jQuery.cleanData( [ elem ] );
                }

                if ( elem.parentNode ) {
                    elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem );
                }
            }
        }

        return this;
    },
```

And the `.cleanData` method which it calls, which mentions a ticket number and allegedly prevents that horrible leak (according to one of the comments):

```
cleanData: function( elems ) {
        var data, id, cache = jQuery.cache, internalKey = jQuery.expando, special = jQuery.event.special,
            deleteExpando = jQuery.support.deleteExpando;

        for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++ ) {
            if ( elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()] ) {
                continue;
            }

            id = elem[ jQuery.expando ];

            if ( id ) {
                data = cache[ id ] && cache[ id ][ internalKey ];

                if ( data && data.events ) {
                    for ( var type in data.events ) {
                        if ( special[ type ] ) {
                            jQuery.event.remove( elem, type );

                        // This is a shortcut to avoid jQuery.event.remove's overhead
                        } else {
                            jQuery.removeEvent( elem, type, data.handle );
                        }
                    }

                    // Null the DOM reference to avoid IE6/7/8 leak (#7054)
                    if ( data.handle ) {
                        data.handle.elem = null;
                    }
                }

                if ( deleteExpando ) {
                    delete elem[ jQuery.expando ];

                } else if ( elem.removeAttribute ) {
                    elem.removeAttribute( jQuery.expando );
                }

                delete cache[ id ];
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the ticket mentioned in the comment. Apparently it was fixed eight months ago:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7054#comment:10

According to Dave Methvin the solution seems to be to *Ensure that the DOM element ref in an event handler is removed by cleanData to avoid an IE6/7/8 memory leak.*

In other words, set references to DOM elements within event handlers to `null` otherwise some awesome browsers, without mentioning any names *cough* IE *cough* will leak memory.

`discardElement` (from your link) inserts the element into a container, and then empties the container, thereby *nullifying* any references to that element.

With that in mind, I would suggest upgrading jQuery. The article you point to is from 2009, and two years is roughly equivalent to four-hundred-zillion man hours of jQuery development time.

Finally, here is some interesting (and ridiculously long) reading on leak patterns in Internet Explorer:

- [Understanding and Solving Internet Explorer Leak Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reasonably go through the entire codebase looking for event handlers to null. Which is why this hackish solution intrigues me. So far as it's proven to be something of a silver bullet that doesn't require manually setting handlers to null.

Comment: @JPRO - not event handlers, DOM elements within event handlers, and you don't have to do that if you're willing to upgrade jQuery to a more recent version.

Comment: Certainly bad code has been a major contributor to the problem, and I could go through it all and correct it, but it would take much more time than I have allocated for this task. We're currently using jQuery 1.6.2. That said I think you've answered the question as to why this works (I came to the same conclusion myself but wanted some more input). Thanks for the info!

Comment: Good answer, i'm quite pleased that the actual fact isn't that far removed from my musings, that is, a reference (pin) is making IE not destroy the object. Good work on this answer though, well researched and typed up , +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to theorise that it's similar to .net garbage collection, in that it relies on Pinned objects in the heap.

IE is treating the parent of a removed object like a pin and not clearing the removed object down properly.

The act of moving the deleted item to this generated gc container is basically removing the pin because IE knows that nothing is relying on that container.

That's my gut feeling anyway.